# Should I begin transitioning from one role to another in the same company before the effective date of the new role?

Tags: promotion, internal-transfer

I have worked for the same company for a while. I am currently a Senior Director and I've applied for and been offered a Vice President Role. I was ready to accept the position with an effective date of the 1st of the next month, but now they are pushing for the start date of the VP position to be several months out. I got the impression that they want me to still begin transitioning out of my current role (because we have a backup plan), then take leave for a couple of weeks and then start the new role.

My position is I will not take on any new VP level work until I start in the role. Is this reasonable? If I was hired from outside the company they would have to have me start and pay me on day one of the role.

Comment: "My position is I will not do any transition work to the new role until it is started. Is this reasonable?" By transition work, do you mean starting the new job (before you formally get the title)? Also, is the leave for their convenience? Are you going to use your own PTO/vacation time for that?

Comment: Given the levels of the positions involved, I'm a bit surprised for you to either not ask your company what the expectations are, or not communicate that you've done so when asking others what to do.

Comment: I was told they needed to fill the VP position immediately. Then when they offered the position to me they said they wanted me to start transitioning to the new role, but not be paid for it until 2 months from now.

Comment: " I got the impression that they want me to still begin transitioning" -- if you aren't sure, ask them. If you are sure, what's the question?

Answer (score 10):

When possible, take every reasonable opportunity to show that you're a team player.

A VP level position in most companies is a top tier management position. It is an upward promotion. I can't stress enough that at this level it shouldn't be treated like a 9 to 5 job.

Is the issue the delta in the money, the title, the PTO, or the added responsibilities?

You've been there for 8 years, it isn't like a new employer asking you to get up to speed before being on payroll.

Unless I am misunderstanding your question, why wouldn't you start the transition?

Comment: I am not the VP yet. The issue is they want me to start acting as the VP but not pay me the VP salary for 2 months.

Comment: @Wholesomegypsea That kind of evaluation cuts both ways. Are you honestly telling me that you're fully capable of functioning as a VP RIGHT NOW? I highly doubt it. Do you not have new teams that report to you as the VP? If so, your operating efficiency is effectively 0 with them. If you're petty with your responsibilities now, it isn't going to look good for your VP career to be honest.

Comment: Two months = 8 weeks = 40 days = a very, very short time in the overall scheme of things. Aren't you be chomping at the bit to get started for the opportunitity that most people would kill for? If you view it as a burden rather that an opportuntity, do you really want this job? I am just asking. Solutions are your new job. "I will not" isn't a solution.

Answer (score 6):

> My position is I will not do any transition work to the new role until
> it is started. Is this reasonable?

To me, it seems ridiculous for a VP to hold their breath and say "I won't" like this.

It's not clear why you are reluctant to do what the company asks. But you aren't being reasonable.

Comment: I'm not the VP yet. What I am saying is if they want me to start taking on VP responsibility then I need to be paid for the VP role. I am already doing more than my current position in the company.

Comment: @Wholesomegypsea Then use a bit more tact to bring it up other than "I'm not paid enough", because that's what you've said. You can tell them "Hey, I still have a lot of responsibilities as managing director. I need to be able to offload them before being able to take on VP duties. What are your succession plans so that I can transition to the VP role quicker?" So much more tact that "I ain't being a VP until I get paid as a VP."

Answer (score 1):

When I switched job, going from an engineering job to another engineering job in a different department in the same company, the transition happened in 1 month, with a gradual transition: I started working 80% in old job, 20% in new job, then moved to 60%-40%, 40%-60%, 20%-80% until switching to 0%-100% on the day I was supposed to start the new job.

This allows for a smooth transition and transfer of responsibilities for all the parts involved in the transition.

If that is true for an engineer, it will be even more true for a soon to be VP, who has to learn and get up to speed with their new job and has also to transfer their current tasks and responsibilities to their replacement.  Ideally I would expect the transition to take longer than the 1 month it took in my case, for the very reason that the amount of learning and transferring involved is bigger.

Saying that you won't do any new role work until the official job starts sounds like you are underestimating the challenges you will be facing and that you assume you will be able to be fully operational from day 1, or that the company can operate with a VP less until you learn all you need to learn.